# Firebase callable functions. Promise is returning null on the client ( Cloud Functions )

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I developed this firebase function to return data from my app search ( elastic ). When I log it at the functions console I can see the request data, and I can also see the response body at my App Search API Logs. But i can not get the data on the client

### Response body

```json
{
  "meta": {
    "alerts": [],
    "warnings": [],
    "precision": 2,
    "page": {
      "current": 1,
      "total_pages": 1,
      "total_results": 2,
      "size": 10
    },
    "engine": {
      "name": "engine",
      "type": "default"
    },
    "request_id": "DF4VEuzuQpWAHH8VCBkvDg"
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "nome": {
        "raw": "Produto legal"
      },
      "_meta": {
        "engine": "engine",
        "score": 0.8957006,
        "id": "bnxvuzVXIQ4BxqHxjvgt"
      },
      "id": {
        "raw": "bnxvuzVXIQ4BxqHxjvgt"
      }
    },
    {
      "nome": {
        "raw": "Produto massa"
      },
      "_meta": {
        "engine": "engine",
        "score": 0.3164503,
        "id": "rdG192xjSVCLIEBNg0la"
      },
      "id": {
        "raw": "rdG192xjSVCLIEBNg0la"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### Firebase function

```js
exports.searchProdutos = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const options = {
    search_fields: { nome: {} },
    result_fields: { nome: { raw: {} } },
  };
  const query = data.query;

  client
    .search("engine", `${query}`, options)
    .then((response) => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.errorMessages));
});
```

But when I try to call it in the client and log the response I get two null objects logged in the console

### Function call on the client

```
  const searchProdutos = httpsCallable(functions, "searchProdutos");
  const getProdutos = async () => {
    const results = await searchProdutos({ query: "produto" });
    console.log(results.data);
  };
  getProdutos();
```

**Aditional info:** I am using Nodejs App Search in my functions and react as my frontend library/framework

**Edit:** I am also getting a 200 response. So I guess there is nothing wrong with the request. I tried removing the .then from my client function but I am still getting `data: {null}` twice

Comment: Remove your first .then

Comment: In the client or at the firebase funtion?

Comment: in the client. I expect if you look at your network logs, you'll see the response, given that your first .then logs the correct value. Because that .then doesn't return the value, the new value of the promise after that .then is `undefined`. In other words, your test .then to ensure the value was correct is actually altering your result.

Comment: I tried calling it with a async function, but I am still getting the error. I edited my question with the changes that you suggested and my test attempt

Comment: Have you checked your network logs to confirm the response is there?

Comment: `exports.searchProdutos` doesn't return anything when called. Should it be?

Comment: So how I get the value resolved at the client.search function and return it in exports.searchProdutos?

Comment: return the promise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238777/discussion-between-davi-cheli-miquelim-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting a Community Wiki answer for this thread in order to have a solution available for future users. Based on the comments from Kevin B in the [chatroom thread](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238777/), there is a [problem](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53376852#53376852) with the client side code which calls your Firebase function. When your client code logs the response with a `then` statement, this `then` statement does not return the response, but an `undefined` value, this makes the response get lost after being logged.

In addition, the server side Firebase function does not return the promise back to the client application inside the `client.search()` function. Based on the chatroom [comments](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53376856#53376856), your Firebase function should return the response from `client.search()`.